# Reguralexpresion which accepts valid float numbers [PHP]

Tags: php, regex, preg-match, conditional-statements

I am trying to verify a valid float number. Basically I want to accept numbers with up to four numbers after the dot or comma:

```
0,2342
123412,2300
1234.0000
1244
1234,12
1234.12
0.23
```

I also want to reject the numbers with leading zeros, but pass the 0 if it's on its own before the dot or comma.

```
01234,1234
00012.2342
01,1234
```

I used this expression, but this did not work as I expected:

```
$number_exp = "<^[0]?([^0][0-9]+)?[.|,]?[0-9]{0,4}$>";
$test = '0123,4342';

if(preg_match($number_exp, $test)) return true;
return false;
```

Anyone know how to condition the statment so it will accept 0 if and only if it's on its own before the delimiter?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All you need is play with capture grouping .You can use the following regex :

```
^(([1-9]+|0|[1-9]+?0)([.,][0-9]{0,4})?)$
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/hA7nH0/4)

Also note that `[^0]` is an incorrect regex because it will match everything except `0` so it will match characters or ...

Comment: well this for some reason will accept $test = '023,4342';

Comment: @GlupiJas Welcome! note about `[^0]` too!

Comment: Btw nice demo toolkit for regex you posted here. Thx for that too

Comment: wont let me accept the answer that qick :) Will do in a minute. Thx

Comment: It doesn't match `10`

Answer (score 1):

How about:

```
/^(?:[1-9]\d*|0)(?:[,.]\d[0,4})?$/
```

**Explanation:**

```
/                   : regex delimiter
^                   : begining of string
    (?:             : start non capture group
        [1-9]       : one digit from 1 to 9
        \d*         : any number of digits from 0 to 9
        |           : OR
        0           : zero
    )               : end of group
    (?:             : start non capture group
        [,.]        : a comma or a dot
        \d[0,4}     : 0 to 4 digits
    )?              : end of group, optional
$                   : end of string
/                   : regex delimiter
```

Answer (score 0):

Already found the solution

```
$number_exp = "<^([^0][1-9]+)?([0]{1})?[.|,]?[0-9]{0,4}$>";
```

But still wondering if there is any other way to do it?